# Can you refer to variables with dashes in jade?

Tags: javascript, pug, frontend

I'm trying to do something like this in my jade template

```
a.apply-url(href="#{apply-url}")
```

But it's being interpreted as 'apply minus url'

Is there a way I can force the interpreter to do the right thing? Or is there some way to refer to a top-level object, and put the index in quotes, like this?

```
a.apply-url(href="#{this['apply-url']}")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not all that familiar with Jade, but I have looked into it a little bit before. After playing around a while [here](http://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs), I was able to get this to work:

```
a.apply-url(href="#{locals['apply-url']}")
```

```
{"apply-url": "foo"}
```

produces:

```
<a href="foo" class="apply-url"></a>
```

This works because this particular implementation stores the data in a local variable named `locals` which is then closed over by the templating function. As far as I can tell, this is an implementation detail, and I wouldn't necessarily expect this to work in other Jade implementations.